# Laravel edit children in parent view

Tags: php, laravel

I try to get children's in their parents view with ability of editing them,

## Codes

`controller`

```
public function edit($id)
{
  $option = Option::findOrFail($id);
  return view('admin.options.edit', compact('option'));
}
```

`blade`

```
// getting parent info in edit blade
{{ Form::model($option, array('route' => array('options.update', $option->id), 'method' => 'PUT')) }}

{{ Form::label('title', 'Name') }}
{{ Form::text('title', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}

{{ Form::submit('Update', array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}

// Geting this option subs (children's) in my second tab
@foreach($option->suboptions as $sub)
{{ Form::model($sub, array('route' => array('suboptions.update', $sub->id), 'method' => 'PUT')) }}

{{ Form::label('title', 'Name') }}
{{ Form::text('title', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}

{{ Form::label('price', 'Price') }}
{{ Form::text('price', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}

{{ Form::submit('Update', array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
@endforeach
```

## Issue

> As my sub's form is inside the loop I get update button for each row
>   (children) how can I only have 1 button?

## UPDATE

check [this video](https://streamable.com/afft2) to see what I mean.

## UPDATE 2

`More explain!`

1. my page `is include 2 different forms` (one of them edits my option
   `eg. size` **that's fine we no have problem with that**)
2. **my second form which is my issue** will return subs of my option, `eg.`
   **option** = `size`, **subs** = `12 inch`, `15 inch etc`.) in order to edit this subs currently i have 1 button for each of them `(as you see in video i shared)`, what i want is to have only 1 button for all of my second form.

Comment: put your button outside the loop

Comment: @devnullΨ but my form opening is inside the loop, is that standard to have opening in the loop and closing out of it?

Comment: you want update button only for first form? you can use `@for` loop and check if its first iteration like `@if($i==0) print button @endif`

Comment: @devnullΨ please see my update.

Comment: I don't clearly understand what you trying to achieve. you have form in loop, that's why you got many buttons. if you want only one button you should print it for only one iteration (I already showed you). but my wild guess is that you need only one form and many inputs in it. if so, move `Form::model`, `submit()`  and `close()` methods outside the loop. if not, be more specific and clarify your question

Comment: bro, my page is include `2` different forms (one of them edits my option `eg. size` that's fine we no have problem with that), (my other form `which is my issue` will return subs of my option, `eg. option = size, subs = 12 inch, 15 inch etc`.) in other to edit this subs currently i have 1 button for each of them, what i want is to have only 1 button for all of it. `The problem with your solution(putting out button and form close is that it will return error because submit button will miss understand id of which entry should be edited)`

Comment: so you need one submit button for multiple forms? check this https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/834325/How-I-can-submit-two-forms-with-one-button

Comment: @devnullΨ ok that sample has `2 forms` and `1 submit`, I have `2 forms` and `I want 2 submits`, _but what i have now is `2 forms` and `3 submits` (ps: 3 is depend on my subs can be more or less)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

I've made controller below and I can update my data as I wanted:

```
public function subsupdate(Request $req)
    {
      for ($i=0; $i<count($req->id); $i++) {

        DB::table('suboptions')
            ->where('id',$req->id[$i])
            ->update([
                'title' => $req->title[$i],
                'price' => $req->price[$i],
        ]);

      }
      return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Suboptions updated successfully.');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just open and close the form *outside* of the loop:

```
// Geting this option subs (children's) in my second tab
{{ Form::open(array('route' => ['suboptions.updateMany'], 'method' => 'PUT')) }}
@foreach($option->suboptions as $sub)

{{ Form::label('title', 'Name') }}
{{ Form::text('title[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}

{{ Form::label('price', 'Price') }}
{{ Form::text('price[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}

@endforeach
{{ Form::submit('Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

You would then implement the updateMany controller method to loop over the submitted data (validate it) and submit it.

Comment: bro have you seen my form opening? `$sub` & `$sub->id` you think they came from where? `FROM MY LOOP` if I put my loop inside my form opening i will get error.

Comment: "bro" have a look at my code above _again_. I don't use $sub/$sub->id within the loop... People here are trying to give you a hand - so go easy on the caps - it can be misunderstood as being aggressive

Comment: Ok - updated. A `Form::model` can only represent a single model

Comment: Ok, this is what i created so far http://collabedit.com/kkrwc and returns nothing

Comment: You are missing the `[]` after title and price as per my answer. Also, as mentioned in my answer, you will need to loop over the submitted data in your controller method

Comment: Ok I added `[]` but sorry i din't get this part `you will need to loop over the submitted data in your controller method` (would you mind edit my codes there?)

Comment: Sorry I don't have time to write your code. Try dump (`dd($data)`) your data so you can see what is being submitted. You will see its just an array - so you would loop over the array, and create/update each model set you find (or convert it to an structured array and bulk insert)